# Find the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with given Plücker coordinates.

Tags: representation-theory, grassmannian

I'm studying Representation theory and I'm trying to understand the Grassmanian and Plücker coordinates. This problem is an exercise from *Young Tableaux: With Applications to Representation Theory and Geometry*

> Find the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^4$ with Plücker coordinates $x_{1,2}=1, x_{1,3}=2, x_{1,4}=1, x_{2,3}=1, x_{2,4}=2$ and $x_{3,4}=3$

I've seen a few different examples but the book only gives the vague idea and I'm having trouble understanding how I should go about finding the subspace they are asking for.

Comment: Do you know the dimension of the subspace you're trying to find?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The exercise does not specifically state the dimension of the subspace. It only says "the" subspace so I just assumed there is only one possibility. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You should be able to work out the dimension of the subspace using the fact that there are six Plücker coordinates (the number of Plücker coordinates depends on the dimension of the subspace). This is the first step.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Going back to the examples given in the book, I would assume the dimension of the subspace would be 2.

Comment: That's correct. So you need to find two vectors $v, w \in \mathbb{C}^4$ which form a basis for the subspace $P$. The Plücker coordinates of $P$ are computed from the coordinates of $v$ and $w$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm not sure if I understand what I need to do. May I have more guidance?

Comment: You need to find $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ and $w = (w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4)$ such that the Plücker coordinates of $P = \operatorname{span}\{v, w\}$ are the given coordinates. You should start with the relationship between the Plücker coordinates coordinates of $P$ and the numbers $v_i, w_i$.

Answer (score 2):

To start with $x_{2,3} x_{1,4}-x_{1,3}x_{2,4}+x_{1,2}x_{3,4}=1\cdot 1-2\cdot 2+1\cdot 3=0,$ the Plücker relation is satisfied. This relation gives the Plücker embedding of the grassmannian $G(2,{\Bbb C}^4)$ of $2$-subspaces in ${\Bbb C}^4$ as a quadric in ${\Bbb P}^5.$

Now the Plücker coordinates $(x_{1,2}:x_{1,3}:x_{1,4}:x_{2,3}: x_{2,4}:x_{3,4})$ are the $2\times 2$-minors of $\begin{pmatrix} a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\b_1&b_2&b_3&b_4\end{pmatrix}$ i.e.

$x_{1,2}=\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_2\\b_1&b_2\end{vmatrix}=1,$
$x_{1,3}=\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_3\\b_1&b_3\end{vmatrix}=2,$
$x_{1,4}=\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_4\\b_1&b_4\end{vmatrix}=1,$
$x_{2,3}=\begin{vmatrix} a_2&a_3\\b_2&b_3\end{vmatrix}=1,$
$x_{2,4}=\begin{vmatrix} a_2&a_4\\b_2&b_4\end{vmatrix}=2,$
$x_{3,4}=\begin{vmatrix} a_3&a_4\\b_3&b_4\end{vmatrix}=3.$

Taking the ansatz $a_4=b_4=1$ and solving $a_1b_2-b_1a_2=1,a_1b_3-b_1a_3=2,a_1-b_1=1,a_2b_3-b_2a_3=1,a_2-b_2=2,a_3-b_3=3$

you get e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} -1/2&0&1/2&1\\-3/2&-2&-5/2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and the subspace you want is the span of the row vectors.

Comment: Do you know a priori that there will be a solution with $a_4 = b_4 = 1$, or did you just try it and it worked?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I tried it and it worked, but it's  also a choice of ${\Bbb A}^3$ in the interpretation of the grassmannian as lines in ${\Bbb P}^3$

Comment: This is inspired by another standard formulation of Plücker coordinates: you can organize them as $(x_{1,2}:x_{1,3}:x_{1,4}:x_{3,4}:x_{4,2}:x_{2,3})$ with the Plücker relation $(x_{1,2},x_{1,3},x_{1,4})\cdot (x_{3,4},x_{4,2},x_{2,3})=x_{1,2}x_{3,4}+x_{1,3}x_{4,2}+x_{1,4}x_{2,3}=0$ and given two points $A=[a_1,a_2,a_3]=(1:a_1:a_2:a_3)$ and $B=[b_1,b_2,b_3]=(1:b_1:b_2:b_3)$ the Plücker coordinates are $(B-A,A\times B).$